# Java EE: Perform one database transaction in two webservice calls

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, transactions, weblogic

I'm working on a Java EE application hosted in **weblogic** (10.3.4.0) and connected to an **Oracle** database. I use UserTransaction to perform database operations. Operations are triggered by **webservices** call from a C++ client. I have **two webservices** that I would like to perform as an **atomic** action, ie rollback to initial state if any exception occurs event during the second webservice call. Note: I can't merge the two webservices into a single one.

I first tried with container-based **transaction**, but it does not seem to fit as I can't control when the commit will happen (I don't want it to occur between the two webservices).
I'm currently trying with stateful bean but didn't yet find a piece of solution. Currenlty all the webservices are stateless.
Would anyone have some advice on my problem, or any hint showing this is not possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are the WSs using the same database?

Comment: Yes, only one database and one jee server.

Answer (score 1):

You may need ws-transaction/ws-coordination modules or service compensation.